# Charles cannot work with VPN?

Tags: vpn, charles-proxy

If I start Charles first, it works fine. If I then open my VPN, VPN starts to work, but Charles stop working. As I understand, VPN and Charles are all network proxy, so only one of them can be the system proxy. But I want them work at the same time. Is there any method to do so? PS.I am using Mac!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Pulse Secure, using this Node package was the only way I was able to get Charles to see the traffic: https://github.com/majgis/psproxy.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Firefox as a browser. I observed the similar behavior as you stated.

To make the Charles work even with VPN connection you have to add Charles Proxy Add-ons in Firefox browser. Here is how you do:

1) Go to Tools -> Add-ons

[image]

2) Select Extensions on the left and search for Charles and hit Install.
[image]

3) Once the download/install is complete, restart the browser.[image]

4) You are all set. Now the Charles should start capturing even with VPN connection.